# What is a "customizable VCL designer guideline" in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-2006

The web page http://www.codegear.com/en/products/bds2006 starts with a list which includes this line:

> - Ensure visual consistency with **customizable VCL designer guidelines**.

Is this related to the 'laser-line' guidelines?
How can these guidelines be 'customized'?

Edit: [This page](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39136) gives additional information about this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They could mean that they are customizable by component writers.  I think the only end user customization is to turn them on or off.

Comment: It looks like this is the meaning of customizable here. The page http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39136 says: "Component designers can also make their components “guideline aware” if their controls have any special requirements for alignment. " - no additional information however, looks like we have to explore the VCL sources (or the documentation?)

Answer (score 2):

This has more to do with the fact that a control can now have "padding" and "margins" which would increase the guideline as it is increased.  The guidelines now react to these properties.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, those are them.

By "customizable", I wonder if they mean that they honour each control's margin settings?  I'm not sure if you can change their behaviour otherwise (aside from turning them on or off).